# How to remove characters from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I want to remove `<< any words #_` from the following string.

```
stringVal = "<<Start words#_ I <<love#_ kind <<man>>, <<john#_ <<kind man>> is really <<great>> <<end words#_ ";
```

Result mast be:

```
Start words I love kind <<man>>, john <<kind man>> is really <<great>> end words
```

I tried like this:

```
stringVal = stringVal.replace(/^.*<<.+\#_.*$/g, "");
```

**But it removes all string.**

Note: `<< any words #_` may exists `multiple` time in string, at the start, in the middle or at the end

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Dz75Hj/1

Comment: @Andreas, thank you for comment, I checked it was same as mine

Comment: Isn't it ```<<john#_``` instead of ```<<john#```?

Comment: I added the comment because of the explanation of your regular expression which should make it clear why it removes everything

Comment: Is it `<<john#_` or `<<john#` ?

Comment: Inferring from your example you might be looking for `<<(\w+)#` which needs to be replaced by `$1`, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3H3VAL/1).

Comment: it is `<<john#_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inferring from your examples, you might be looking for:

```js
stringVal = "<<Start words#_ I <<love#_ kind <<man>>, <<john#_ <<kind man>> is really <<great>> <<end words#_ ";

stringVal = stringVal.replace(/<<([-\w ]+)#_/g, "$1");
console.log(stringVal);
```

To allow other characters, change the `\w+` to e.g. `[-\w ]+`.
See [**an additional demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3H3VAL/3).

Comment: @Muhammad: No, then you need to change the expression to `[-\w ]+` as stated in the answer in the end.

Comment: thank you and now only does not work at the `start` and at the `end`: like `->` `<<#hello_ I <<lo and ve#_ kind <<man>>, <<john#_ <<kind man>> is really <<great>> <<#he llo`

Comment: @Muhammad: Please edit your question and put all your required conditions in there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.+\#_`, and you want to match `any words` you could match word characters optionally repeated by matching a space space and word characters.

```
<<(\w+(?: \w+)*)#_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kh5ktF/1)

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

Note that you don't have to escape `#`

```js
const regex = /<<(\w+(?: \w+)*)#_/g;
stringVal = "I <<love#_ kind <<man>>, <<john#_ <<kind man>> is really <<great>>";
const result = stringVal.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers works well, and also this works well `<<(\w+)#_` from @Anreas

Comment: @Jan, is right if there is space does not work by the I up voted for the efforts thank you

Comment: @Muhammad If there can be any words as in plural, this could be another option `<<(\w+(?: \w+)*)#_` https://regex101.com/r/kh5ktF/1 If there can not be underscores in the word, only after the `#` then this might also be an option `<<([^\W_]+(?: [^\W_]+)*)#_` https://regex101.com/r/eoyrYB/1